# How can I connect multiple MCP23017's to an arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am working on a project and I am trying to figure out how to connect multiple MCP23017 IO Expanders to one arduino. All of the guides that I have found in my quest for information only explain how to connect one MCP chip or how to address multiple MCP chips. None seem to explain how to connect them physically. BTW, I am talking about the I2C version of the chip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know how to connect one chip you know how to connect many chips.  One or eight it's the same.

All the SCL pins connect to the SCL pin of the Arduino. All the SDA pins connect to SDA on the Arduino.

Just make sure that each chip is given a unique address using the A0-A2 pins as detailed [in the datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/20001952c.pdf).

Comment: One to eight is the same, ten is too much with three address bits.

Comment: You can also address them all with the same address, and use the A0-A2 pins as a chip select.  For example, have discrete pins connected to A0s, and have A1, A2 connected to Gnd. Have A0 held high in the code.  When you want to talk to a device, bring A0 for that device low, use the I2C address for A0-A1-A2 =0, then bring A0 for that device back high.  Next device, use the next A0 line, and so on.  You could expand even further, with A1/A2 = 0,0,  and 0,1, and 1,0, and 1,1, with 32 slave select lines (fed by 4 shift registers even, with just 3 control lines needed to load the shift registers).